# How to send syslog to mongodb of mlab?

Tags: mongodb, syslog

I can not send syslogs of device(etc. own computer) because mongodb in MLAB is not authorized. I can send to local MongoDB at the moment, but I can not send it to the remote MongoDB. What should I do? Please help me.

Comment: How are you trying to send syslogs to MongoDB? Are you able to connect from the `mongo` shell to your mLab deployment? If you are getting as far as a "not authorized" error it sounds like you just need to use the correct connection string and credentials. If you need help with a programming question, can you update your question with details of your MongoDB driver version and a code snippet showing how you are trying to connect.

Comment: I am sending syslog-ng to mongodb by modifying the log server's conf setting. How can I control MLab MongoDB with shell? obviously this problem is not related to coding.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how syslog-ng integrates with MongoDB, but if it can log directly to MongoDB I expect you just need to configure the correct credentials to connect to your mLab deployment (and have appropriate firewall/network access). What are your versions of syslog-ng and MongoDB server? Can you include an example of your syslog-ng configuration (with any credentials/hostnames replaced with placeholders)? It looks like the main value you need to configure is a  `uri()` in the standard [MongoDB Connection String](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) format.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "control mLab MongoDB with a shell". Are you referring to connecting to mLab with the `mongo` shell, running some commands  in a `bash` or console shell, or something else entirely? You should be able to connect to your mLab deployment with the `mongo` shell, and doing so from your environment with syslog-ng would be a good test that you have the correct credentials and required network access.

Comment: I solved the problem with a different method. thanks for your help.